# Euler's Totient function $\forall n\ge3$, if $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ n\ $ then $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1$ is prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, conjectures, multiplicative-function

While I was studying [Euler's Totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), $\varphi(n)$, I stumbled upon the marvelous book "Index to Mathematical Problems, 1980-1984" By Stanley Rabinowitz. [In this page of the book (link to Google books sample)](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=n-F52zK2UAgC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=%22anders%20bager%22%2B%22fibonacci%22&source=bl&ots=cyt_L7xSlY&sig=MoeakB4ZvXLPWW7PQLO4ECmcC34&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fJ0sVYnbLoPw8gXh04DwDQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22anders%20bager%22%2B%22fibonacci%22&f=false), the open problems and conjectures about the Totient function appear. All are really awesome, but one of them was specially interesting to me:

CMB34 by M.V.Subbarao:

> if $(\varphi(n)+1)\ \mid\ n$ then, $n$ or $n/2 \in \Bbb P$.

Well it has two parts, the 'trivial' one is that if $n$ is indeed a prime number, $\varphi(n)=n-1$, so $\varphi(n)+1 = n-1+1 = n$, and then $n \mid n$. But the other part is not trivial: when $(\varphi(n)+1)$ divides $n$ (even), then $n/2$ is a prime number. Simply amazing and still open (if I am not wrong).

I wanted to learn more, so I did my own try-outs of other combinations like CMB34, and I did find one that is very interesting, indeed I did not find any open conjecture or open problem about it, so here is my own proposed statement:

> (1) $\forall n\ge3$, if $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ n\ $ then $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\in \Bbb P$

And it really seems to work! I have made a Python test in the interval $[1,50000]$ and the statement is always true, no counterexamples. Here are some samples:

$n = 52,\ \varphi(n)=24,\ \frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1=13,\ 13\mid52$, and $13 \in \Bbb P$

$n = 57,\ \varphi(n)=36,\ \frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1=19,\ 19\mid57$, and $19 \in \Bbb P$

$n = 66,\ \varphi(n)=20,\ \frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1=11,\ 11\mid66$, and $11 \in \Bbb P$

$n = 68,\ \varphi(n)=32,\ \frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1=17,\ 17\mid68$, and $17 \in \Bbb P$

$etc.$

Having those results in mind, I tried to generalize to $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2^i}+1, i\in\Bbb N$. And for instance for the case $i=2, (2^2)$, apart from some specific initial small $n$ counterexamples $n = \{3,4,6,28,36,66\}$, for $n\gt66$ seems to be always true as well. I still did not try other values of $i$.

I have uploaded the [test written in Python here](http://hobbymaths.blogspot.jp/2015/04/eulers-totient-function-statement.html).

I have continued trying to generalize, and the following statement seems also to be true always:

> (2) $\forall n\ge3, n=2k,\ k\in \Bbb N$, if $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ \frac{n}{2}\ $ then $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\in \Bbb P$

There are two differences with my main statement $(1)$: in this case, $n$ can only be an **even** number $\ge3$, so it can be divided by $2$, and the relationship is true when a factor of $n/2$ is found (instead of a factor of n). I will update the question if I find more successful combinations.

The same can be applied to those $n$ multiples of $4$, and in this case, the expression is (trivially) true when $n = 4p\ \forall p \in \Bbb P, p\ge3$, so the list of **odd** primes appears in the original natural order of the prime numbers:

> (3) $\forall n\ge3, n=4k,\ k\in \Bbb N$, if $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ \frac{n}{4}\ $ then $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\in \Bbb P$

This is in other words:

> (3) $\forall n\ge3, n=4k,\ k\in \Bbb N$, if $\frac{n}{4} = (\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)$ then $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\in \Bbb P$

In this case, the relationship is trivial for those $n=4p$ multiples of any $p$ prime, because

$\frac{\varphi(4p)}{2}+1 = \frac{\varphi(4)*\varphi(p)}{2}+1 = \frac{2*\varphi(p)}{2}+1 = \varphi(p)+1 = p-1+1 = p$

But the interesting point is that if $n$ is a multiple of $4\ /\ n\not=4p, p \in \Bbb P$ then the relationship is false always, so no primes are found. Anyway, the expressions (1) and (2) seem more interesting than (3).

I did not find any $n$ able to make the relationship true for $\frac{n}{8}$ or $\frac{n}{16}$.

The prime numbers $p = (\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)$ generated by the expression (1):

1. Except for the case $n=6$ in the rest of cases the prime number $p$ seems to be always the **greatest prime factor** of $n$.
2. Trivial but interesting, if $p$ is factor of n, then $(n/p)$ is an upper bound of the other prime factors of $q$, so $\forall q, q\in \Bbb P\ /\ q \not= p, \ q\mid n, \ q\le(n/p)$.

And n is a subset of the numbers following the pattern:

> $n=(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)*k_1 /\ k_1 \in \{2,3,4,6\}$

It could be possible that I can not see the wood for the trees, and my statement is trivial, or already known, or nonsense, so I would appreciate any help to understand those results.

> I would like to share with you the following questions:
>
> 1. Is my proposed statement about the Totient function already known or trivial?
> 2. Is there a counterexample of it?
> 3. Could it be generalized?

Thank you!

** UPDATE 2015/04/22 ** My definition about the numbers $n$ covering the properties explained at the statement (1) has been accepted at OEIS! ([link here](https://oeis.org/A256241)).

** UPDATE 2015/05/01 ** Related question about other possible interesting property ([link here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258928/eulers-totient-and-divisors-count-function-relationship-when-frac-varphin)):

> (2)$\ \forall n\in [3,29]\cup[31,1000000]$,
>
> if $[(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ n]\ \land\ [(\frac{\tau(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ n]\ $ then $[(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\cdot(\frac{\tau(n)}{2}+1)] = n$

Comment: @barto, thank you very much for the changes, much better now!

Comment: (+1) Nice question! amounts to asking for the set of primes $S = \{p_1,\cdots,p_k\}$ s.t., $\frac{1}{2}\prod\limits_{p \in S} (p-1) + 1 \vert \prod\limits_{p \in S} p$ :)

Comment: @r9m cool, I did not think about it in that way :)

Comment: Note that if $n=3p$, $n=4p$, or $n=6p$ where $p$ is a prime, then $\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1 = p$, so the divisibility property holds in these cases.

Comment: There are no counterexamples through $n = 10^7$.

Comment: @rogerl many thanks for the explanation, while I study the properties I make try-outs and tests, so everything is new to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not so difficult to see that your desired statement,

> (1) $\forall n\ge3$, if $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\ \mid\ n\ $ then $(\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}+1)\in \Bbb P$

is true if the [Lehmer Totient Conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer's_totient_problem) would be true (I am not sure about only if). This means that the statement (1) is a simple consequence of the Lehmer Totient Conjecture (a very difficult conjecture).

Comment: thank you for the reference, any hint is very welcomed.

Answer (score 4):

Now I understand that this is the generic version of expression (1):

> $\forall\ n=pk\ ,\ p\in\Bbb N\ , $ if $\exists\ m\ /\ \varphi(m)=k\ $ , then $\frac{\varphi(pk)}{\varphi(k)}+1 = p \mid n$

So the property is true only if the denominator of the fraction is one of the possible values taken by the totient function ([OEIS link here](https://oeis.org/A002202)) and the numerator contains a prime and a $k$ whose value $\varphi(k)$ is exactly the value of the denominator.

For instance for the family $k\in \{5,8,10,12\}$ whose $\varphi(k) = 4$ , the valid $n$ are $n=kp$ and the valid expressions are $\frac{\varphi(p5)}{4}+1=p$,$\frac{\varphi(p8)}{4}+1=p$, $\frac{\varphi(p10)}{4}+1=p$,$\frac{\varphi(p12)}{4}+1=p \mid n$.

The sequence for the case $k=2$ is very easy to convert into code and check running through $n$ so it deserved a place in the OEIS database ([link here](https://oeis.org/A256241)).